# Button Won't Move Next to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to put my button next to my edit text similar to a search bar you see when searching something on Google. I want to move the button on the right side next to search bar but I don't understand why RelativeLayout is not working here. I read some similar questions posted on Stack and the answers said to use RelativeLayout for most of them. Is there another type of layout I should be using instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:layout_width="283dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:autofillHints="@string/search"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/search" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this Line at Button to add a constraint

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/searchBox"
```